# import my local module in python3 so it can i installed in the system via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I have a directory structure as:

```
   tree
    .
    ├── bin
    │   └── mkbib.py
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── mkbib
    │   ├── __init__.py         #empty file
    │   ├── menubar.ui          #a xml file. where should I place it?
    │   ├── menu.py
    │   ├── pybib.py
    │   └── view.py
    ├── mkbib.desktop.in    #should be copied to /usr/local/applications
    ├── README
    └── setup.py
```

with `bin/mkbib.py` is the main file, which imports the files in `mkbib/`. And in `bin/mkbib.py`, I use:

```
import mkbib.menu as menu
import mkbib.view as view
# import view
# import pybib
```

If all files are in same directory, last two lines are enough. I separated them as per the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742203/create-a-python-executable-using-setuptools).

But, now, when I am trying to run the code, I am getting error:

```
 File "mkbib.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.TreeView = view.treeview()
NameError: name 'view' is not defined
```

My ultimate goal is to install the `mkbib` app in the `/bin/`, same as the question I have linked, but I don't have any success.

My `setup.py` is :

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
with open(path.join(here, 'README'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='mkbib',
    version='0.1',
    description='BibTeX Creator',
    url='https://github.com/rudrab/mkbib',
    author='Rudra Banerjee',
    author_email='bnrj.rudra@gmail.com',
    license='GPLv3',
    packages=['mkbib'],
    package_dir={'mkbib': 'mkbib'},
    scripts=['bin/mkbib.py']
    )
```

When I run `setup.py`, I get;

```
 sudo python3 setup.py develop
running develop
running egg_info
writing top-level names to mkbib.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing mkbib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to mkbib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'mkbib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'mkbib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mkbib.egg-link (link to .)
mkbib 0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing mkbib.py script to /usr/bin

Installed /home/rudra/Devel/mkbib/Mkbib
Processing dependencies for mkbib==0.1
Finished processing dependencies for mkbib==0.1
```

I have also tried exporting pythonpath to the `mkbib`:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
~/Devel/mkbib/Mkbib/mkbib
```

As I said, if all the files are in same directory, its working flawless.

**The `mkbib.py`'s structure is(as asked by  GeckStar)**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi
import sys
# import mkbib
import mkbib.menu as menu
import mkbib.view as view
# import view
# import pybib
import urllib.parse as lurl
import webbrowser
import os
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio  # , GLib, Gdk
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")


class Window(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, application, giofile=None):
        Gtk.ApplicationWindow.__init__(self,
                                       application=application,
                                       default_width=1000,
                                       default_height=200,
                                       title="mkbib")

        self.TreeView = view.treeview()
        self.MenuElem = menu.MenuManager()
        self.Parser = pybib.parser()
        self.name = ""

.........
class mkbib(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)
        self.connect("startup", self.startup)
        self.connect("activate", self.activate)
..........

def install_excepthook():
    """ Make sure we exit when an unhandled exception occurs. """
    old_hook = sys.excepthook

    def new_hook(etype, evalue, etb):
        old_hook(etype, evalue, etb)
        while Gtk.main_level():
            Gtk.main_quit()
        sys.exit()
    sys.excepthook = new_hook


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = mkbib()
    r = app.run(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(r)
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you actually *run* the `setup.py`, to install the package?

Comment: jonrsharpe yes, but mistakenly I have shown the older `setup.py` with different file structure. Correct (atleast current) `setup.py` and the run is included now. Kindly have a look.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of your `mkbib.py` file, especially the first 26 lines since that's where the error happens.

Comment: I can't really see why the `NameError` is being raised. It usually happens when you are using a function or class with an ambiguous name. I'd suggest you to try to import `mkbib.view` with another name, or change the name of the `mkbib` folder and see if it works then.

Comment: @GeckStar: After I `build` the system, now its giving ImportError for menu and others, if I run from out of Mkbib dir. This is because, the contents of `mkbib` are placed inside a `build/lib`, but not placed in /usr/lib/python3.5...

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue if they've been added to PYTHONPATH correctly. You have to add the root directory of your project to PYTHONPATH and then execute the main script from that root. What you've run into is the problem polarise was talking about in his/her answer.

Comment: But pythonpath is already added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118135/discussion-between-geckstar-and-barud).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of Python's quirks: setting up paths to modules and packages. In your case, after you install the `mkbib` package `bin/mkbib.py` should simply have:

```
import mkbib
```

without any changes to `PYTHONPATH`. This is because `bin/mkbib.py` is designed to be used as a binary and assumes that `mkbib` package is already on the default `PYTHONPATH`. You can test whether `mkbib` is on the unmodified `PYTHONPATH` by running:

```
$ python -c 'import mkbib'
```

which should do nothing.

Python takes as reference the current directory `.` in resolving relative paths, which is why your setup works when all files are in one folder.

Comment: I don't think its pythons's problem....if you need to run a executable, you have to place its dependecies in proper place.Your comment is valid, only when the mkbib/ directory is also placed in suitable directory, e.g. `/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/`, and this is the question: How I can do that.

Comment: You need to install the package with `python setup.py build && sudo python setup.py install`. I assumed you had already done that.